# Traversing a graph in clojure

Tags: graph, clojure, functional-programming

Hope you are well. I am stuck with a recursive program that is suppose to traverse a graph until it finds a path back to the start node. the code is here,

```
(def graph {:A {:B 5 :D 5 :E 7}
            :B {:C 4}
            :C {:D 8 :E 2}
            :D {:C 8 :E 6}
            :E {:B 3}
            })

(defn looper [g startnode & args]  
  (let [[inode] (vec args)
        acc []]
    (if (= startnode inode)    
      (conj acc inode)    
      (conj acc inode (map (partial looper g startnode) (vec (keys (get g inode)))))
  )))


(looper graph :C)
```

there is something wrong with the way I accumulate the result I couldnt find what exactly.

The function should return something like '(CDC CEBC) for the above call.

Comment: Are you expected to enumerate all the combinations? For instance, `A -> B C, B -> A, C -> A` has two such paths: `A -> B -> A` and `A -> C -> A`.

Comment: @Thumbnail thanks for the reply, yes that shld solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick, hope its helpful for someone :)

```
(defn- dfs
  [graph goal]
  (fn search
    [path visited]
    (let [current (peek path)]
      (if (= goal current)
        [path]
        (->> current graph keys
             (remove visited)
             (mapcat #(search (conj path %) (conj visited %))))))))
(defn findpath
  "Returns a lazy sequence of all directed paths from start to goal
  within graph."
  [graph start goal]
  ((dfs graph goal) [start] #{start}))

(defn circular-path-count [graph node] 
  (flatten (map (fn [s]
       (map count (findpath graph s node))) (vec (keys (get-in graph [node]))) )))



e.g. usage: (circular-path-count paths :B)
```

Comment: What does `dfs` refer to here?

Comment: @DanielCompton Oops I missed the dfs function. thanks for pointing it out! :)